# "El que..." to mean "That that..."

Tags: pronombres

I read a sample sentence somewhere, and I am confused about the use of "el que."

> Hija mía, el que eso te preocupe es buena señal de que tú, por lo
> menos, no vas a permitir que eso ocurra. Y ahora háblame un poco de
> esa nueva computadora que anuncian tanto en la tele.

Why is *el que* used here instead of *el hecho de que*? I have never seen this use of *el que*, and I had a hard time finding more examples to this discussion. Doesn't *el que* usually mean "the male thing or person that..."? I am very confused by this.

Comment: That is not really a standard form. It's just a shortened colloquial form like You got milk? For Have you got milk? It means the same thing as el hecho que eso etc.

Comment: Well technically standard form is "Do you have milk?", right? But that's very helpful to know. I had a feeling it was nonstandard, but you never know for sure as a non-native speaker.

Comment: Is it really a non-standard form?  I would have thought it's just an issue of register.

Comment: In English: **have you got** = **do you have**; two ways to say the same thing. Two simple present tenses for the verb to have. **Got milk?** is a very well-known TV advertisement. It is a shortened form from Have you got milk. If they had used: Have milk? The ad wouldn't have worked as that it not catchy.

Comment: Sorry, I am more or less a native AmE speaker, so understand the "got milk" paradigm.   It was "el que" that didn't strike me as equally "non standard."

Comment: @Vegawatcher I was talking to Sebastian, not you. el que as used there is non-standard. You can't just use el que to refer to something that has not yet been mentioned like that.

Comment: @Lambie Could one say that "el" roughly stands in place for "the fact" or with the situation in general? AKA "The current situation in which this concerns you is a good sign..." I agree that it's kind of odd to use the pronoun "el" without an antecedent.

Comment: The fact that this is **worrying you** is a good sign. :) concern is over-translation here. preocupar in everyday speech is usually worry. :)

Comment: HAHA I agree worry is a better translation. By the way, why is present subjunctive used here? This doesn't strike me as something that calls for subjunctive. I know Spanish is pretty trigger-happy compared to English when it comes to subjunctive (ex. sin que requires subjunctive when it is totally unnecessary in English).

Comment: ^^ Put it another way, does it sound wrong to say "El hecho de que eso te **preocupa** es una buena senal..."?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I feel that the existing answers don't fully address what the OP was asking. I will also try to answer the additional question (added by the OP in a comment) as to why the subjunctive, rather the indicative mood, is used in these cases.

Basically, 'el que' is often interchangeable with 'el hecho de que' and is a very common idiom, also in formal Spanish, at least in Spain. It is usually the same as using a plain introductory 'que'.

But whereas 'el hecho de que' can be followed by a verb in either the subjunctive or  the indicative mood, with '(el) que' only the subjunctive is used.

Let's take the following English sentence as an example:

- The fact that Argentina has won the world cup can be put down to the
  excellent team work over the last four years. (1)

We can translate this into Spanish in four ways:

- Que Argentina haya ganado el mundial puede atribuirse al excelente trabajo de equipo de los últimos cuatro años. (1a)
- El que Argentina haya ganado el mundial puede atribuirse al excelente trabajo de equipo de los últimos cuatro años. (1b)
- El hecho de que Argentina haya ganado el mundial puede atribuirse al
  excelente trabajo de equipo de los últimos cuatro años. (1c)
- El hecho de que Argentina ha ganado el mundial puede atribuirse al excelente trabajo de equipo de los últimos cuatro años. (1d)

Using an indicative 'ha' with '(el) que' in sentences 1a and 1b would sound weird. A possible explanation for this preference for the subjunctive is that the fact introduced by '(el) que' can also be an assumption or possibility in the future, and not only a true, verifiable fact that is occurring now or has occurred in the past. This other case in which a future possibility is implied is often expressed with 'whether' in English, as in the next example:

- Whether Spain will have any options to win the 2026 world cup will depend on the team work they do over the next four years. (2)

Here the translation using '(el) que' is:

- Que España tenga opciones de ganar el mundial de 2026 dependerá del trabajo de equipo que se haga en los próximos cuatro años. (2a)
- El que España tenga opciones de ganar el mundial de 2026 dependerá del trabajo de equipo que se haga en los próximos cuatro años. (2b)

In this case, we cannot paraphrase "(el) que" with "el hecho de que", but we can use "la posibilidad de que". Since we are talking about an imagined scenario in the future, the subjunctive is always required:

- La posibilidad de que España tenga opciones de ganar el mundial de 2026 dependerá del trabajo de equipo que se haga en los próximos cuatro años. (2c)

The example in the original question uses a fact about the present ('that worries you'), so we're in the realm of the examples I labelled as 1, and we can say:

- Hija mía, que eso te preocupe es buena señal [...]. (1a)
- Hija mía, el que eso te preocupe es buena señal [...]. (1b)
- Hija mía, el hecho de que eso te preocupe es buena señal [...]. (1c)
- Hija mía, el hecho de que eso te preocupa es buena señal [...]. (1d)

The four versions are correct and have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

El relativo "el que" y sus variantes, el que, la que, las que, lo que, los que.

El pronombre relativo introduce un personaje o concepto del que ya se ha hablado anteriormente en la oración.

[image]

---

**CONTEXTO**

- Por supuesto, pero tengo que aprender tanto antes de poder dedicarme a estos problemas. Además, me preocupa que la modernización resulte en una pérdida de sensibilidad humana.
- Hija mía, **el que eso te preocupe** es buena señal de que tú, por lo menos, no vas a permitir **que eso** ocurra. Y ahora háblame un poco de esa nueva computadora que anuncian tanto en la tele.

---

**ESO** como pronombre demostrativo neutro, **se emplea para** indicar o señalar algo o a alguien próximo al interlocutor, o **referirse a una idea o frase que se acaba de mencionar**.

---

En estos casos el relativo "que" puede ir precedido de un artículo determinado o manteniendo su función de pronombre, "el, la, lo" formando las siguientes locuciones "el que, la que, lo que, las que, los que".

---

"Hija mía, el que eso te preocupe es buena señal de que tú, por lo menos, no vas a permitir que eso ocurra. Y ahora háblame un poco de esa nueva computadora que anuncian tanto en la tele".

Significado extenso;

Hija mía, **el que** **eso** = (**de que la modernización resulte en una pérdida de sensibilidad humana**) te preocupe  es buena señal de que tú, por lo menos, no vas a permitir que **eso** = (**que se pierda la sensibilidad humana**) ocurra. Y ahora háblame un poco de esa nueva computadora que anuncian tanto en la tele.

En este caso "el que" como relativo, no va precedido de una preposición, por lo que solo se puede emplear en oraciones explicativas entre comas, referido a un antecedente, persona o cosa que enlaza con una actuación, hecho o momento previo y que en este caso hay que sobrentender. Así "el", en "el que", actúa como pronombre y sirve tanto para poner de relieve la forma enfática, como la abreviada de sustitución de una motivación, hecho, situación o actuación preliminar, "el (hecho de) que... **eso**".

- Oración en que sin, "el", la frase mantiene su sentido.

"Hija mía, que eso te preocupe es buena señal de que tú...

- Oración, "el que", donde se enfatiza la frase, y "el" como pronombre, sustituye a un sustantivo, en este caso "hecho", con el sentido de acción, obra, suceso, motivación, actuación o acontecimiento anterior. **Es una forma introductoria a un hecho que se ha mencionado en el párrafo anterior al que se hace referencia y al que se vuelve enfatizar con el pronombre demostrativo** "**eso**".

"*Hija mía, el (**hecho de**) que (**eso**), te preocupe es buena señal de que tú...*

**EXPLICACION DE LA FRASE CON SENTIDO EXTENSO**

Hija mía, **el que eso**, **"el que eso"** = (**de que la modernización resulte en una pérdida de sensibilidad humana**) te preocupe es buena señal de que tú, por lo menos, no vas a permitir **que** **"eso"** = **(que se pierda la sensibilidad humana**) ocurra. Y ahora háblame un poco de esa nueva computadora que anuncian tanto en la tele.

---

*Hija mía el que la modernización resulte, en una pérdida de sensibilidad humana y te preocupe, es buena señal de que tú, por lo menos, no vas a permitir que esa perdida de sensibilidad humana ocurra. Y ahora háblame un poco de esa nueva computadora que anuncian tanto en la tele.*

Comment: Desafortunadamente no entendí la mayor parte de esto, pero muchas gracias por esta respuesta. La última frase responde perfectamente a mi pregunta.

Comment: Idea completa. *Hija mía el que la modernización resulte, en una pérdida de sensibilidad humana y te preocupe, es buena señal de que tú, por lo menos, no vas a permitir que esa perdida de sensibilidad humana ocurra. Y ahora háblame un poco de esa nueva computadora que anuncian tanto en la tele.*

Answer (score 0):

> Hija mía, **el que** ***eso*** te **preocupe** es buena señal de que tú, por lo menos, no vas a permitir que eso ocurra.

- ESO = the thing to avoid = it or that (the fact, received information) Ej: Una injusticia, una desgracia, una negligencia, etc, que se está cometiendo.
- *ESO2* => EL QUE+SE/TE preocup**e** preocup**es**(subjuntivo presente) <s>preocupas</s> = her/your apparent concern about the situation, the apparent reason why you/she shouldn't let that happen, that she's/you're worried about/could be concerned ej. La aparente preocupación que observa la madre que su hija está experimentando para que eso no se cometa/no se vaya[subj. present] a cometer por su intervención, la de su hija) (It's just an impression)

ESO can be omitted.

- EL QUE (ESO) te preocupe es buena señal de que, por lo menos, no vas a permitir que (ESO) ocurra.